# load second version of jQuery(using multiple version)

Tags: jquery

I working on a application which uses older version of jQuery and it has so many features built with it. Now I need to use latest version of jQuery without affecting the older one. `$` and `jQuery` should always point the older one and I can have any alias( say `jQueryNew` ) pointing to newer version. how can I achieve this?

> NOTE: I am building over the existing framework(like building
>   extensions) and has no control over the native features.
>
> [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)
>
> This provides the solution to change the alias of older before loading
>   the newer one. I looking for a way load the new version without
>   changing the older alias

Comment: search `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: @PranavCBalan I went through it but when I load the newer version, automatically it moves the older `jQuery` to `_jQuery`. only if the newer version is loaded, I can change the alias with `noConflict`. Correct me if I am wrong.